# Outlook: how to filter emails that explicitly mention my name in body

Tags: regex, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to filter emails that directly mention my first name in the body of the email.

For example, the following email

> John, please finish the report.

should be filtered.

However, the problem is that I'm CC'd on a lot of email chains irrelevant to me, and when someone hits reply all, my name is always matched by Outlook rules because the quoted reply message contains the To: and CC: fields, where my name shows up.

For example, the following email

> Everyone, please finish the report.
>
> ---
>
> From: Test, Jane Sent: Friday, August 28, 2015 12:51 PM To: Test, Joe 
>   Cc: Test, Bill; Doe, John Subject: Report
>
> Original email text here.

has nothing to do with me, but still gets filtered with the emails that are relevant to me because I'm matched in the CC: field.

So far, I set up a rule with an exception where the message gets filtered if "John" appears in the body, unless "Doe, John" appears in the body. However, the problem with this is that it filters out emails that may not initially be relevant to me, but become relevant to me further up in the reply chain.

For example, the following email

> From: Test, Jane Sent: Friday, August 28, 2015 12:51 PM To: Test, Joe 
>   Cc: Test, Bill; Doe, John Subject: Report
>
> John, please mark this report as finished.
>
> ---
>
> From: Test, Jane Sent: Friday, August 28, 2015 12:51 PM To: Test, Joe 
>   Cc: Test, Bill; Doe, John Subject: Report
>
> Everyone, please finish the report.
>
> ---
>
> From: Test, Jane Sent: Friday, August 28, 2015 12:51 PM To: Test, Joe 
>   Cc: Test, Bill; Doe, John Subject: Report
>
> Original email text here.

wasn't initially relevant to me, but is now relevant to me. However, it doesn't get filtered because my exception matches "Doe, John" further down. This problem is exacerbated by the fact that rarely is my email address in the To: field.

Is there any workaround to this using Outlook rules? If not, is there a convenient way to do this using VBA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This simple regex should help you

```
^From:.*\n.*(John).*
```

Explanation

`^From:`: starting of line by `From:`,

`.*`: follow by any text,

`\n`: follow by a newline (here is end of email header),

`.*(John).*`: any text that contains `John` in the body.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD1eQ2/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, is there a way to do this without VBA? The reason I ask is because if I set one of my rules to run VBA, the script will only work when Outlook is running. That means that emails that come in when I'm sleeping won't get filtered by the rule.

Comment: For sure, just a tiny perl/python script can done this.

Comment: You just write any program to check it every time you open it, filter the email task totally not take time.